# Wrapping a text file in a war and in a jar format

Tags: spring-boot, text, jar, war, packaging

I have a springboot program that reads from a text file present inside the project. I use eclipse IDE. I want to share the project. While packaging the project in war format the text file was missing. Can someone tell me how do I package it so as to have the text file inside the package ?
I want to know the steps for both war and jar packaging which will include the text file in them.

This will let the user who unpacks it finds the text file and it can be used by the springboot service directly.

Thanks

Comment: I have the text file directly under my project and not inside any other folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put any resources (files) used at runtime in `src/main/resources`. They should be available in all packages.

Comment: HI Hubert,
I tried this but still the war file is missing the text file. Only Meta-Inf Web-Inf and index.html are getting packaged into the war.

Comment: Can you suggest any other way.